# How to reuse jdbc connection in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a data frame from an Oracle table.  In order to reduce the data retrieved, I try to write out the keys derived from input files to a temp table first then do a join. 
The code is like

```
Dataset df = session.createDataFrame(keys, schema); 
df.write().mode(“append”).jdbc(url, “mytemptable”, prop); 
df=session.read().jdbc(url, “select * from Account a inner join mytemptable t on t.key=a.key);
```

However, it always returns 0 row, which implies both write and read use different jdbc connections.  If We convert to pure jdbc code, the query works as expected.

Is there a way to cache a jdbc connection in a Spark session?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.